# How to scroll in PhpStorm terminal with keyboard?

Tags: phpstorm, keyboard-shortcuts

When I press up or down arrow keys - it uses history. I tried various combinations.  Page up, page down. Nothing makes it scroll up/down. Only I can do it with mouse.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: @chocochaos - win 10 as host and ubuntu as guest, and run phpStorm on ubuntu.

Answer (score 6):

This is possible in **2016.3** (it's in **EAP** stage at the moment and [current public EAP build](https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2016/10/phpstorm-2016-3-eap-163-6512/) already having it).

The shortcuts are <kbd>Shift + PageUp</kbd> and <kbd>Shift + PageDown</kbd>.

Right now it looks like those are hardcoded shortcuts (cannot be customised by user).

Original ticket: [IDEA-142926](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-142926)

Comment: Is this like beta version?

Comment: @Darius.V EAP = Early Access Program .. so yes -- sort of Beta/nightly dev build. You can safely try it -- it keeps settings separate so can be run in parallel to your current IDE version. Just backup project settings (`.idea` subfolder; just in case) as they may not be backward compatible. Please also note that since it's EAP .. it may have some changes that are not yet complete in full (e.g. in Deployment)